# How to return first 50 characters of text in LINQ call

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql

I have a small winapp that uses LinqToSQL as it's DAL.  I am creating a summary view of all the CaseNotes for a given person and one of the fields is a Details box.  I need to return only the first 50 characters of that column to my treeview function.

Any hints on how I do that?  The below is how my TreeView function gets its data for display  and the ContactDetails is the column in question.

```
        public static DataTable GetTreeViewCNotes(int personID)
    {
        var context = new MATRIXDataContext();
        var caseNotesTree = from cn in context.tblCaseNotes
                        where cn.PersonID == personID
                        orderby cn.ContactDate
                        select new { cn.CaseNoteID,cn.ContactDate, cn.ParentNote, cn.IsCaseLog, cn.ContactDetails };

        var dataTable = caseNotesTree.CopyLinqToDataTable();
        context.Dispose();
        return dataTable;
    }
```

---

### ANSWER

I am posting this here in case any future searchers wonder what the solution looks like in the questions context.

```
        public static DataTable GetTreeViewCNotes(int personID)
    {
        DataTable dataTable;
        using (var context = new MATRIXDataContext())
        {
            var caseNotesTree = from cn in context.tblCaseNotes
                                where cn.PersonID == personID
                                orderby cn.ContactDate
                                select new
                                           {
                                               cn.CaseNoteID,
                                               cn.ContactDate, 
                                               cn.ParentNote, 
                                               cn.IsCaseLog, 
                                               ContactDetailsPreview = cn.ContactDetails.Substring(0,50)
                                           };

            dataTable = caseNotesTree.CopyLinqToDataTable();
        }
        return dataTable;
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx):

```
var caseNotesTree = from cn in context.tblCaseNotes
                    where cn.PersonID == personID
                    orderby cn.ContactDate
                    select new {
                        cn.CaseNoteID,
                        cn.ContactDate,
                        cn.ParentNote,
                        cn.IsCaseLog,
                        ContactDetailsClip = cn.ContactDetails.Substring(0, Math.Min(cn.ContactDetails.Length, 50))
                    };
```

Also, I would suggest wrapping your use of [`DataContext`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx) in [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) blocks.

Comment: The problem with this is if the text in ContactDetails is not 50 characters in length you will get an exception. What you do is something like...

 ContactDetailsClip = cn.ContactDetails.Length > 50 ? cn.ContactDetails.Substring(0, 49) : cn.ContactDetails;

Comment: @Chalkey:  When I first read your comment I was like "Of course" but interestingly it does not error out.....I'd love to know why.

Comment: @Chalkey: Use Math.Min(length of string, clip length). See edit.

Comment: @Jason: isn't it Math.Min instead ?

Comment: @Refracted Paladin: That code will compile, it wont crash until run time. Its just like this line- String s = "Hello".Substring(0, 100); - will compile, but crash at runtime.

Comment: @Chalkey:  I understand what you are saying.  What I am saying is that it is not crashing at runtime.  Even with empty or less then 10 characters present in the details field.  In fact it works perfect and I am curious why as what you say makes sense and I would have expected a fail.

Comment: @Refracted Paladin: Not sure, I've just made it throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException by substringing to much than is available.

Answer (score 5):

With LinQ you can also do the following :

```
new string( myString.Take(50).ToArray() );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cn.ContactDetails.Substring(0, 50);
```

In the "select new" line.  Does that work?

Comment: You have to give the result a name, too.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ syntax

```
string message=new string(myString.Take(50).ToArray());
```